# What can I conclude about the ROC of a transfer function in discrete time

Tags: signal-processing, laplace-transform, z-transform

I have a discrete system with transfer function $$ H\left(z\right)=\frac{a_{2}b_{2}z^{-2}+\left(b_{2}a_{1}+b_{1}\right)z^{-1}+\left(b_{0}+b_{2}\right)}{a_{2}z^{-2}+a_{1}z^{-1}+1} $$

Where \$ a_1,a_2,b_0,b_1,b_2 \$ are given real constants which are not zero.

given that \$ z=\frac{|a_{1}|+|\sqrt{a_{1}^{2}-4a_{2}}}{|a_{2}|} \$ is in the ROC, can I determine what is the ROC?

Here's what I have tried:

One may notice that the poles of this function are given in \$ z^{-1}=\frac{-a_{1}+\sqrt{a_{1}^{2}-4a_{2}}}{2a_{2}} \$ and \$ z^{-1}=\frac{-a_{1}-\sqrt{a_{1}^{2}-4a_{2}}}{2a_{2}} \$

Now, the following inequality holds:

$$ \frac{|a_{1}|+|\sqrt{a_{1}^{2}-4a_{2}}|}{2|a_{2}|}<\frac{|a_{1}|+|\sqrt{a_{1}^{2}-4a_{2}}|}{|a_{2}|} $$

My only problem is that my poles are actually where for \$z^-1 \$ and not for \$z\$ so I feel like I need more information about the constatns in order to determine the ROC.

I have been thinking about this problem for a while and I feel like I'm missing something simple, so I'll really appreciate your thoughts here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*My only problem is that my poles are actually where for z^−1 and not for z*". Why is that a problem? Can't you not convert it in terms of z ?

Comment: Start by converting the transfer function into standard form (multiply top and bottom by z^2) and then solve for the poles. This should get you far enough.

Comment: @AJN Because then I cant tell what is the relation between them (whats bigger)

Comment: @Ryan It dosent really help because in that case we get poles at \$\frac{a_{1}\pm|\sqrt{a_{1}^{2}-4a_{2}}}{2}\$ and I dont know the relation between \$2\$ and \$a_2\$

Comment: @euler exactly. Your region of convergence will change depending on if a2 is bigger or smaller than 2

Comment: @euler0.0 This is a good homework question, thanks for the attempt at a solution